# Any techniques for evading frequency based crypt analysis without encrypting?

Tags: cryptanalysis, reference-request

Are there any general techniques for evading frequency based crypt analysis without using any encryption techniques?

Comment: Why would you need to evade cryptanalysis period if you aren't using encryption?

Comment: Your question isn't really clear. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Compression tends to flatten frequencies, but is of course designed to be undone and thus has no crypto value by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at ["Chaffing and winnowing: Confidentiality without encryption"](http://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/pubs/Riv98a.pdf), RL Rivest, CryptoBytes (RSA laboratories), 1998.  You can find the paper on scholar.google.com

Comment: Yes i looked at this , thx ! but that doesnot help me .

Comment: @sashank [`but that doesnot help me`](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1870/any-techniques-for-evading-frequency-based-crypt-analysis-without-encrypting#comment3018_1876) – That comment really confuses me… if the answer was not helpful to you, why did you accept it?

Answer (score 3):

**No**.

Frequency-based cryptanalysis aims at breaking an encryption technique; hence *evading frequency-based cryptanalysis* implies an encryption technique.

Because frequency-based cryptanalysis is a poor attack, even some ridiculously weak encryption technique may evade frequency-based cryptanalysis. For example, putting the symbols alphabetically on two rings, using that as a correspondence table, and sliding the rings by one step after each use *evades frequency-based cryptanalysis*, at least in basic form.